# Is it possible to connect to CRM Online from a Visual Studio Team Services extension?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm developing custom Visual Studio Team Services extension and this extension add to Work item custom page. I would like to know if is it possible to connect to CRM Online from the current extension and query data with the authenticated user. Thanks.

Regards,

Comment: You could use Dynamics CRM & 365 Developer Extensions for visual studio to connect to CRM https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JLattimer.DynamicsCRMDeveloperExtensions

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have to use CRM online js/ts clients to query data. Since the user is already logged in, you should be able to query data from CRM. We have many extension that query Power BI

Here is one for example.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=InsightsLab.powerbiWidget

Comment: Hi, Is it possible to post some code example? We are getting CORS exception.